# Change the background of a div depending on the position of the scrollbar without it looking like it loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, parallax

Basically I saw this page [THIS PAGE](http://www.smokeybones.com/#deals) and if you scroll up and down you can see the glass of drink becoming full and empty depeing on where your scrollbar is. Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty complex to do stuff like that but not particularly hard.

First, you'll need to manage this using something like jQuery. You got that already so good...

The html below is a working example that assumes the user has an image:
[image]

it is 700 x 100. The code is pretty simple. Round the window's scrollTop() value and figure the right frame offset based on the results. No need to fully explain, the code below says it all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<style>
#main{position:relative;}
.dummy{height:500px;}
#glass{
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:url(http://www.hep-g.com/glass.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var frame = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() % 100 < 10)
            frame = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / 100) * 100;

        if(frame > 700)
            frame = 700;

        $('#glass').css('background-position', '-' + frame + 'px 0');
    });

});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <section class="dummy">
            This is dummy content
        </section>
        <section id="glass"></section>
        <section class="dummy">
            This is dummy content
        </section>
        <section class="dummy">
            This is dummy content
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would it be possible to create a simple example? the scrolling bit is the main part, i know how to do simple sprites for example changing the position of a background when someone hovers over it, however this is to do with scrolling. It would be AWESOME if you could!

Comment: maybe if I get some extra time. It could take a while to set up a working example

Comment: Ok, I made a working example. Check my answer for the link and code.

Comment: thank you so very much. I really appreciate that! You can remove the actual page, just please keep the image in the correct directory so I can see it working on my test server too.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually one image with the background-position changing.  The image is completely loaded by the time you see the glass originally.

http://www.smokeybones.com/static/img/tv/beer_sprite_lrg.jpg?e3e4e50f54ea

Comment: so depeding on where the scrollbar is they just move the position of the image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/td657/ I copied the code out (they have it compressed).  It looks like they call animate with the current percentage when scrolled and update the position based on that.